# How does Google determine the hash for search terms?

Tags: java, hash

How does Google hash a user's search query? Obviously the hash is determined by the text in the query, but does google exclude common words like "the" or "a". There are other factors to hashing a search term that could make it a faster process, such as not looping through each character in the term (if possible). Also, are other factors like the country in which the user reside play a role pre-hashing or post-hashing, in other words are other metrics besides the text of the query included in the hash?

In Java the function `hashCode` can be used to find the hash corresponding to the object passed as the implicit parameter. Would Google really just use a standard `hashCode` function?

I'm sure this is possibly one of Google's "secrets", but does anyone have an idea of how it's done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They remove the stop works from the query. Here is an [article](http://www.seobythesea.com/2006/02/google-looks-at-multi-stage-query-processing/) which talks about it.
The query processing sequence is [here](http://www.seobythesea.com/wp-images/token5.GIF).